# notepad++ how to choose word autocomplete suggestion by pressing TAB not RETURN (default )?

Tags: notepad++

i just enalbed autocomplete in notepad++

but when the suggestions come up, you have to hit RETURN key to choose it...is there any way to make TAB autocomplete ?

also, it seems like curly brackets and normal brackets are not autocompleting ! anyway to enable ?

Answer (score 1):

The closing with tab should be suggested as a code change, since it is not enabled now.  That can be done through the [IdeaTorrent](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/most_popular_ever/).

The second question is that auto completing brackets is an option through the standard TextFX plugin under TextFX Settings.